# Embed a password protected vimeo video in Slider Revolution 6

Tags: wordpress, slider, vimeo, revolution-slider

I am using the Slider Revoulution 6 plugin on a wordpress site.
In the background I want to show a vimeo video which is password protected.

There can be set arguments(query parameters) but setting a password parameter does not help here.

How can I get this to work? Ist that even possible, or do I have to change my privacy settings on the video.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a valid reason to password protect the video, or is it only so that you can control who watches the video and where?

Currently password protected videos are only accessible by the owner of that video and the people with the password and link to the video. You cannot send a password to that video with an argument or through API.

You can try setting the video to private, so that it is hidden on Vimeo itself, but can still be played on your site.

Comment: Probably you are right and the video does not necessarily need to be password protected, but It would have been easier because the video was provided by me and I do not own it. Thanks for the answer.